# displaying data in default.phtml magento 2.0

Tags: magento, magento-2.0

i would like to add data from the magento database (an extra label put in the product) to all my pages which shows the price of the product, i *think* it could be done via extending all default.phtml files.

at this moment the default.phtml has;

```
<td class="item-price">
    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $block->getItemPrice($_item); ?>
</td>
```

i want to expand it with;

```
<td class="item-price">
    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  $block->getsoort($_item); ?>
</td>
```

This is done by creating all default.html files in /mytheme/Magento_catalog/etc.etc.etc.

What happens according to my thinking; now every where the price is displayed, also the label "soort" of the mentioned product is shown.

Is this a right assumption?

Comment: Okay, so i started trying in any file possible and found out that the default.phtml inside vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/price/amount creates the box wherein the price is displayed. inside this file i put before the span the text "verhuur" and it displays nicely everywhere i want it. However, this is a TEXT i just put into the file, i would like it to be the data from the products DB, i made a attribute "soort" and just want that to display.

Comment: I also found out that the line echo $block->getDisplayValue(); gives the value when i echo it, however, if i do echo $block->getSku(); or echo $block->soort();  then it shows nothing. How do i display Sku or soort?

Comment: Does it stil need to be fetched somewhere or does it need to be added to be send to somewhere??

Comment: https://mage2.pro/t/topic/202 showed me how to get the data  from the db